# .net PDF writer/creator

Tags: pdf-generation, pdf-writer

I have a need to create PDFs from HTML content with specific layouts. I have looked around quite a bit and the only options I could come up with worth any repute are SuperWebGoo and PDFSharp. PDFSharp hasn't been updated in 2 years whereas SuperWebGoo is about 500 dollars per server. SuperWebGoo is pretty promising and I have done a trial of this product and seems suitable for my needs.

I am looking for any open source .NET products to accomplish my goal with samples. Any inputs are appreciated. Thanks a bunch!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used ABCPDF and it was a good product to work with. Simple to use and awesome support.

Answer (score 0):

Look at iText.  It is open source and just might do what you want.  As for documentation, Manning has a book called iText in Action  (http://www.manning.com/lowagie/)

Comment: iText/iTextSharp are not free (as in beer) for commercial applications

Comment: Agreed with Bobrovsky. iTextSharp needs a license.

Comment: iText/iTextSharp - you must either release all of the source code for your application or purchase a license.